# Raphael.js how to find click on path's stroke?

Tags: javascript, svg, click, raphael

How can I find out with Raphael.js (when the user click on a SVG path) the click was on the stroke?

Here is the path:

```
var polycoords = [['M',10,10],['L',30,10],['L',35,50],['L',5,45],['Z]];
var poly = paper.path(polycoords).attr({'stroke':'#00f','stroke-width':5});
poly.click(function(e) {
    // I think here can I find it somehow...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as your path it closed but not filled with a color or a pattern, only the strokes are clickable, so the problem seems to resolve itself.

If in some not pasted code lines, you actually fill this path, then, also the inside is clickable and there is no difference in the event argument provided to the click callback.

Two ways:

1. having the stroke and the inside as two differents path (one filled and without strokes, the other not filled but with strokes) and attach seperate click handlers
2. on click, create a temporary path surrounding the pixel you clicked (whose coordinates are in the event argument), and search for intersections with the existing path with `Raphael.pathIntersection(path1, path2)` ([RaphaelJS documentation: pathIntersection](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.pathIntersection))